# Plot polar scatter plot with images as markers, matplotlib: cannot convert NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a pandas dataframe I have some code that will create a scatter plot and place a specified png at each point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import BboxImage
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox, TransformedBbox

threshold = 0.05
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bound = 0.2
ax.set_xlim([-bound,bound])
ax.set_ylim([-bound,0.25])
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')

for index, row in high_low.iterrows():
    x = row['row1']
    y = row['row2']
    if abs(x) > threshold or abs(y) > threshold:
        im = plt.imread('/path/to/my/image_' + str(index) + '.png')
        bb = Bbox.from_bounds(x,y,.01,.01)  
        bb2 = TransformedBbox(bb,ax.transData)
        bbox_image = BboxImage(bb2,
                            norm = None,
                            origin=None,
                            clip_on=False,
                          alpha=0.75)

        bbox_image.set_data(im)
        ax.add_artist(bbox_image)

ax.grid(True, color="black", linestyle="--")
plt.savefig("myfig.svg", dpi=300, format='svg')
```

I want to change this plot to polar coordinates, so I added the following function

```
def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return(rho, phi)
```

and changed my code to:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True) # <- CHANGE HERE
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
for index, row in high_low.iterrows():
    x = row['row1']
    y = row['row2']
    if abs(x) > threshold or abs(y) > threshold:
        rho, phi = cart2pol(x, y) # <- CHANGE HERE
        im = plt.imread('/path/to/my/image_' + str(index) + '.png')
        bb = Bbox.from_bounds(rho,phi,.01,.01)   # <- CHANGE HERE
        bb2 = TransformedBbox(bb,ax.transData)
        bbox_image = BboxImage(bb2,
                            norm = None,
                            origin=None,
                            clip_on=False,
                          alpha=0.75)

        bbox_image.set_data(im)
        ax.add_artist(bbox_image)
ax.grid(True, color="black", linestyle="--")
plt.savefig("myfigPolar.pdf", dpi=300, format='pdf')
```

The loop runs:

```
...
<matplotlib.image.BboxImage object at 0x7f6b805fb390>
<matplotlib.image.BboxImage object at 0x7f6b805fb6d0>
<matplotlib.image.BboxImage object at 0x7f6b805fba10>
...
```

but I get the following error when plotting:

```
>>> plt.savefig("myfigPolar.pdf", dpi=300, format='pdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1952, in print_pdf
    return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2352, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 1182, in draw
    im = self.make_image(renderer, image_mag)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 1172, in make_image
    im.resize(int(widthDisplay), int(heightDisplay),
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Neither `rho` nor `phi` are `Nan`, nor are they super small floats (which I've seen causing this error in other Stackoverflow answers).

**Edit**: In response to the comment asking for `plt.show()`

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 1182, in draw
    im = self.make_image(renderer, image_mag)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 1172, in make_image
    im.resize(int(widthDisplay), int(heightDisplay),
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Min and max values of `rho` and `phi`

```
>>> min(rho), max(rho)
(0.10336371748137782, 0.22005286472537541)
>>> min(phi), max(phi)
(-2.9088677009635697, 1.3618299263576035)
```

Comment: The error occurs when you are saving, not when you are plotting. Might be a bug in savefig. Can you see the plots with plt.show()?

Comment: I get a similar error (added it to the post)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with a minimal example that I coded up. I don't have access to the tkagg backend but agg worked just fine so I don't think that is the problem. What is your matplotlib version (`matplotlib.__version__`)?

Comment: Also, its choking on the images. Are you sure none of them are corrupted?

Comment: version = 1.3.1. The cartesian coordinate plot works fine, both plots are working with the same set of images.

Comment: I am stumped. Before you try upgrading to something less ancient, can you humor me and substitute for your images a random array, e.g. `im = np.random.rand(100,200)`?

Comment: My first guess was that `Bbox.from_bounds(rho,phi,.01,.01)` can't take polar coordinates but couldn't find any info as to whether or not that is allowed.

Comment: Same error when substituting `im = np.random.rand(100,200)`

Comment: What are the minima and maxima for rho and phi?

Comment: Added min/max to post

Comment: Bbox is indeed the issue - the combination of polar and negative coordinates produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass positive angles to Bbox, apparently. This should work:

```
def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    if phi < 0:
        phi += 2 * np.pi
    return(rho, phi)
```

Comment: Thanks! Gets rid of the error though all images are in the top right quarters.

Comment: Presumably because both, x and y, are strictly positive? At least one of them has to be negative if you want the image in any of the other 3 quadrants.

Comment: Definitely not the case. If they were both strictly positive would I get negative `phi`? Plotting x and y I get images in both the 1st and 3rd quadrants.